# Call variable in function from observer excute function

Tags: magento2

I create event with observer and execute it . In execute function I get API 
respond `(PDF file)` How can i call this respond from another class ?.Please reply me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with store your value into session variable.

after get this value into your function, you can destroy it.

try below code if you want to use of session variable

```
protected $_coreSession;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession
    ){
    $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
}

public function setValue(){
    $this->_coreSession->start();
    $this->_coreSession->setMessage('The Core session');
}

public function getValue(){
    $this->_coreSession->start();
    return $this->_coreSession->getMessage();
}

public function unSetValue(){
    $this->_coreSession->start();
    return $this->_coreSession->unsMessage();
}
```

Comment: Pls check my update